# Can we replicate Spark's .cache() behavior but by saving parquet file instead?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lazy-evaluation, parquet

Say I have 4 block of spark instructions represented as Dataframe A, B,C and D.

The dataframe have dependencies :

- C require A & B to be done
- D require B to be done

Now I want to save both C and D output.
In order to not recompute B twice I use

```
B = B.cache()
```

As is, if I save C first I have A & B running in parallel then C and then when I save D it will only need to compute D and this is somewhat good enough scheduling.

**Now the issue is :** If instead of caching B I save it in parquet like this

```
B.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(CacheLocation)
B = spark.read.parquet(CacheLocation)
```

This speed the whole run at least 10x faster than using B.cache() (and 30x faster than not using any cache at all on B)

The problem with the above approach is now I can't run both A and B at the same time unless I use Futures and decide to cache A as well. I'm very performance constrained and my real code have more than 50 blocs/4 outputs to sync which is a nightmare unless I can use Spark's default scheduling.

I was wondering if there is any way to override Spark's cache method to save as parquet instead of memory? Or any ways to add such parquet caching within Spark's own scheduler?

Pseudo code illustration :

*Scenario 1 : using caching, the whole run in 300s but A and B run in parallel*

```
val A = parquet.read(A).withColumn(NewA,FormulaA)
val B = parquet.read(B).withColumn(NewB,FormulaC).cache
val C = A.join(B, FormulaA===FormulaC,left)
val D = B.withColumn(NewD, FormulaD)
C.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(SaveCLocation)
D.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(SaveDLocation)
```

*Scenario 2 : using parquet as caching, the whole run in 30s but A and B run serial*

```
val A = parquet(A).withColumn(NewA,FormulaA)
var B = parquet(B).withColumn(NewB,FormulaC)
B.write.parquet(CacheLocation)
B = spark.read.parquet(CacheLocation)
val C = A.join(B, FormulaA===FormulaC,left)
val D = B.withColumn(NewD, FormulaD)
C.write.parquet(SaveCLocation)
D.write.parquet(SaveDLocation)
```

Comment: What you write does not make sense to me. IO is always the slowest possible solution. I suspect the reason that you experience it as 10x faster is because the B-dataframe is not actually cached when you call C and D. Remember that Spark does lazy evaluation, so is there action (like say a `count`) forcing the evaluation (and hence caching) of B before you use it in C and D? Maybe if you can supply a bit more code?

Comment: I can see the caching is behaving like i mentioned above on the SparkWebUI so i'm pretty sure that is not the issue. 
When i save C i do C.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(SaveLocation) and its the first time in the that B is evaluated.

There must something about the parquet format that make all my operations which are like (filters, join and if/then waterfall) much faster than a cached dataframe. My code is too complex to be put here, if there is hope for my case i can try setup dummy code which reproduce the problem.

Comment: `write` will force evaluation of you B-dataframe. If you only use `cache()` and are not doing anything to force B to be evaluated (and hence cached) BEFORE using it in D and C, Spark is not evaluating (or caching) B until it has to start evaluating D and C, which would explain your performance difference.

Comment: Also, it would really help, if you could supply the code you use for, so that we can see exactly the order of your evaluations and your use of `cache` and `write` respectively....

Comment: i added code illustration

Comment: Thank you - see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

From what you posted here, my suspicion is right.

B is NOT evaluated (or cached) in you `cache` scenario before this action

```
C.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(SaveCLocation)
```

In your `parquet` scenario however, B is evaluated (and stored) on this action:

```
B.write.parquet(CacheLocation)
```

In other words, you cannot compare execution times of `val C = A.join(B, FormulaA===FormulaC,left)` in the two scenario, because in one scenario B is already evaluated and just needs to be read in from disk, and in the other it has to evaluate B first.

Try to add a `B.count` in your cache scenario - it will force evaluation of B in the same way that `B.write` does in you parquet-scenario. Then compare runtimes of `val C = A.join(B, FormulaA===FormulaC,left)` in the two scenarios - I'm sure you will see a big advantage to the cache scenario :)

```
val A = parquet.read(A).withColumn(NewA,FormulaA)
val B = parquet.read(B).withColumn(NewB,FormulaC).cache
B.count // force evaluation of B
val C = A.join(B, FormulaA===FormulaC,left)
val D = B.withColumn(NewD, FormulaD)
C.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(SaveCLocation)
D.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(SaveDLocation)
```

Comment: sorry i might not have phrase it correctly what i'm comparing is the time to run A+B+C+D in both scenario. Otherwise yes that would not be apple to apple.

Comment: Could you still try adding the `B.count`? (caching while doing a `join` is - in my experience - not a good idea...)

Comment: By adding the count spark will compute B first, once done it will compute A, then C then D all in serial. It's hard to believe this could be faster than computing A and B,  in parallel, while caching B then compute C then D. That said I will try to do that to get an idea of how much slower just for fun :)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the parallel nature of Spark. With or without `B.count`, each action will start a parallel evaluation of the stages leading up to that action. But the actions themselves are not evaluated in parallel. So, in your case it will evaluate - and complete - `C.write` before it even considers `D.write`. (and actions, btw, are `count`, `write`, `collect`, `take` and `first`. Nothing is evaluated until one of these are called).

Comment: tried on a subset of the code on for the save C time instruction we got Parquet=52s, CACHE+count =469s, and in addition to that just creating the DAG when using cache took an 80s extra so in total its 549s vs 52s. So using cache() is definitely not an option. Checkpoint might works better for the DAG build up but really parquet is the fastest option. Need to find a way how to schedule the parquet operation within Spark scheduler for maximum parallelism.

Comment: Without the count Spark will run A and B in parallel when doing C.write, that is very clear when looking at the SparkWebUi.
With the count Spark will run B first and then when we do C.write it will run A then C.

Comment: @Simon, I think you should go with whatever you feel like, but please read up on spark stages and stage boundaries. I'm obviously not doing a good job of explaining this to you, maybe someone else will do a better job - I will just finish by emphasizing that using `write` only to cache things is not optimal in spark.